# How to draw touch-enabled rect in Android

Tags: android, drawing, touch

I'm drawing shapes with canvas.drawRect() but i would like to enable touch so that when the user taps on them i can handle the event.
How can i draw touch-enabled rects?

Answer (score 3):

Maintain a map of the available rects you draw and compare the touch points to see if they intersect.

e.g.

```
if (Rect.intersects(MyDrawnRect, RectWhereITouched)) {
    // Touched the rect so handle accordingly
}
```